# Using external programs inside azure-functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm actually developing a POC on Azure Functions.

I actually need to renders PDF from LaTex and the best way to do that is to use some external program usually.

So far what I understood is that I need to use a custom Dockerfile where I can install any external programs and then use them from my Azure Functions, is that the correct way?

By doing this way, when I try to create a Function App in the Azure Portal, I select "Docker container"

[image: image1]

and then I cannot select the "Consumption" Plan, I must go for the "App Service" / "Premium"

[image: image2]

Well, I can still select the Free plan, so it's still fine.

But then it's NOT creating a "Function App" but a simple "App Service".

How I can then deploy on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. You'll need to use the Azure Function image and deploy it to Containers Running on Web App:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base